# Access array inside JSON element using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

How do I access an array nested inside a JSON element with PHP.  Here is the code I'm using (simplified for the example), I can access `from_email, html, subject` etc. easily, but how would I access the `to` email address `recipient@addresshere.co.uk`? Do I need some sort of `foreach` loop, on the basis that there could be more than one entry?

JSON

```
{
    "event": "inbound", 
    "msg": {
        "dkim": {}, 
        "email": "myemail@addresshere.co.uk", 
        "from_email": "example.sender@mandrillapp.com", 
        "headers": {}, 
        "html": "This is an example inbound message.", 
        "raw_msg": "Received: from mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com", 
        "sender": null, 
        "spam_report": {}, 
        "spf": {}, 
        "subject": "This is an example webhook message", 
        "tags": [ ], 
        "template": null, 
        "text": "This is an example inbound message.", 
        "text_flowed": false, 
        "to": [
            [
                "recipient@addresshere.co.uk", 
                null
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

PHP

```
$emailp = urldecode($_REQUEST['mandrill_events']); // The above JSON
$email = array_pop(json_decode($emailp));

$from_email = $email->msg->from_email; // From email
$html = $email->msg->html; // HTML Message
$subject = $email->msg->subject; // Subject
$to = ????
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would access the `to` like this

```
$email->msg->to[0][0];
```

If you want to loop around the whole array you could do

```
foreach ($email->msg->to[0] as $i=>$v) {
    echo "i = $i and v = $v\n";
}
```

Or if you wanted to loop the whole `to` structure you could

```
foreach ($json->msg->to as $i=>$v) {
    foreach ($v as $ii=>$vv) {
        echo "ii = $ii - vv = $vv\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could, as you suggest, loop through the array with `foreach`. For example this would echo the "to" addresses:

```
$to_arr = $email->msg->to[0];
foreach($to_arr as $to) {
    echo 'TO = '.$to.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: I found that if I decode JSON with the "true" flag(associative array) and then save it, any blank entries get saved as indexed array. So for example, the reader has "headers":{ }  in his code, but using true and saving would change it to "headers":[ ]

Answer (score 0):

Using `true` as second function parameter, objects will be converted into associative arrays.

```
$email = json_decode($emailp, true);
```

Then you can easily access any data from the array, even use foreach if needed.

```
print_r($email['msg']['to']);
```

Resuling in

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => recipient@addresshere.co.uk [1] => ) )
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly Associative arrays are faster than objects, and, personally for me, have better readability when working with.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you expect from the data. Since it's an array, it could have 0 or more elements in it. How do you plan to deal with all the cases? If you expect to only even have one, just take the first element. If you want all of the emails in an array then take the entire thing `$to = $email->msg->to;`.

If you're going to use this information to fire of actual emails, then yes, you do want to iterate over all the elements.

```
$msg = new Email();
$msg->setSubject($subject);
// more logic
foreach($recepients as $recepient) {
    // assuming element 0 is email and element 1 is name
    $msg->addRecepient($recepient[0], $recepient[1]);
}
```